# What is the easiest way to populate a uitableview with a huge list of data?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, populate

I've made a uitableview before but with minimal cells. I was wondering how to populate the table with 100 plus names, and each have and individual detail view according to their name.
Also, searchable. Thank you.

Note: this data is copy and pasted from a website. I currently have it in an excel document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to make a `plist` file from the data with the following `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>Name 1</key>
    <string>Description 1</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>Name 2</key>
    <string>Description 2</string>
  </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Add this file to your application. When you want to access it, you do this by

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array =[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];OfFile:path];
```

Now you have an `NSArray` containing `NSDictionaries`, each of which has the information you need for your `UITableView`.

All you need to do now is to populate the `UITableView` using this array. Do this by implementing these two methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Create your cells
    NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // use the key and description however you like in your cell
}
```